「西片と夕日　見れたしね」means "saw sunset with him" or "saw both him and sunset"？

screenshot is from 「からかい上手の高木」S3E2
The official Chinese subtitle is "毕竟见到了西片和夕阳", which means "西片和夕阳 都看到了"（saw both Nishikata and the sunset）
The funny is there is a comment, asking people's opinion if her words have two meanings:

Saw both Nishikata and the sunset (same with the subtitle)
Saw sunset with Nishikata together


then a guy repied to this comment saying that as an international student in Japan, this should be translated as "saw xxx with xxx together"
I've also checked the Japanese subtitle, it is 「西片と夕日　見れたしね」
My questions are:

if there is no context, are these 2 translations both correct?
if both are correct, which is more frequently used?


Is there any ambiguity, at least theoretically, in 跟西片一塊看到夕陽?

@aguijonazo No. If 跟西片 is placed before 看到夕陽 then it strictly means "see the sunset along with 西片", where 西片 is the subject, aka the viewer with the MC, not the viewed with the sun. But in the subtitle above the translator put 西片 after the verb 見到了 along with 夕陽, so if we didn't know what the original Japanese was, the Chinese sentence could only mean "saw sunset and 西片", where 西片 is the object. I guess the confusion comes from people who knew Japanese and noticed the mismatch. Unlike Japanese which has particles to tell apart subject/object Chinese is very dependent on sentence order

@dvx2718 大正解，哈哈

Technically speaking, this is ambiguous. However, practically speaking, a sentence like this is intuitively interpreted as "I could see the sunset with you (Nishikata)", and native Japanese speakers usually won't even notice the other possibility. In an ordinary anime, this is the end of the story.
However, in this anime, the heroine (Takagi) seems to be a character who likes to tease the boy (Nishikata) with ambiguous lines and suggestive behaviors, so we might need to take this into consideration. Before this scene, Takagi actually intentionally teased Nishikata about his red face with a comment that can be taken in two ways:

高木「真っ赤だね」
西片「え、違っ」
高木「夕日！」
西片「…えっ」
高木「ん？」
西片「…なんでも。」
高木「まあ、西片の方が赤いけど！」

Since Takagi's character is like this, the interpretation "I could see the sunset and you" might also be valid, and some may notice the ambiguity or consider this to be an intentional "からかい". Still, the straightforward English subtitle is "I could see the sunset with you". Given the boy's natural response after this line, I don't think we need to worry about the tricky interpretation like "the sunset and you" too much.
(I don't speak Chinese, so I don't know if you can simulate this ambiguity in Chinese.)

haha. Indeed Takagi-san always says something ambiguous to Nishikata.
The straightforward English subtitle should be more close to native Japanese compared to the Chinese version. The first time I saw this scene (subtitle) I never thought there might be ambiguity. "see sth with sb" & "see A and B" are completely different expressions in both English and Chinese.
Thanks for the detailed explanation!! now I understand how the native Japanese audience feels when watching this scene, this particular line.

「頭が赤い魚を食べる猫」を思い出させたね。それは日本語の特徴の一つかなぁ
